# Google Maps API: infoWindow flickers/closes automatically because of mouseout event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, event-listener

I'm in the midst of creating polygons on a spiffy new project I am working on. The problem arises whenever you hover over the infoWindow, the mouseout event on the polygon fires. I don't want the mouseout event to fire unless the mouse moves outside of the polygon AND the infoWindow. Any ideas? Here's most of the relevant code.

```
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: myContent
    });

    var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
          paths: polygonPath,
          strokeColor: data.color,
          strokeOpacity: 0.5,
          strokeWeight: 0,
          fillColor: data.color,
          fillOpacity: 0.5,
          id:polygonId,
          name: data.name,
          shortDesc: data.short_desc,
          map: map 
    }); 


    google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', function(e){
          infoWindow.open(map);
          infoWindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'mouseout', function(){
          infoWindow.close();
    });
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of `mouseout` of the polygon observe `mousemove` for the map(this will not fire when the mouse moves over the polygon or the infowindow)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', function(e){
      infoWindow.open(map);
      infoWindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
      google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'mousemove', function(){
        infoWindow.close();
      });
});
```